# Erlang thread pool

Tags: java, erlang, threadpool, gen-server

with Erlang, how can I achieve a java thread pool?

like the Java API, `ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, RejectedExecutionHandler handler)`

I can define **core thread**, **time to kill thread**, and define policy to **discard/reject tasks**.

I used this pool to send http request to other service. if the remote server was down, the Java system will be still stable.

I tried Erlang `Gen_server`, and user `gen_server:cast` to process the request.

with `gen_server`

```
  it will control the process and make the system stable.
```

the question is

```
   1.  how to kill the process if it take too long?
   2.  how define policy to discard/reject request?
   3.  is that possible to limit the total process?
```

Comment: take a look at [poolboy](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy)

Comment: @Lol4t0. thanks. I think it was too heavy to my function.  actually,  i don't want a gen_server.  I was thinking an `Queue` for task + `spawn a process`, but not quite sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the `worker-pool` [topic](https://github.com/topics/worker-pool?l=erlang) on Github tagged for `erlang`. I get the impression that `worker_pool` might suit you. It has both one (see overrun) and three (see size) of your requirements.